Can anyone help me to understand the proof of the following lemma or give me its proof in detail
Recently, I have been reading a paper about Calderon-Zygmund estimates. I master how to use this method to obtain the interior estimates of solutions in elliptical case. However, when reading the second part for the parabolic equation, I do not understand one of lemmas in this paper:
There is a constant $C$ depending only on the dimension so that
$$
{\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}} \left|u-\bar{u}_{Q_{1}}-\overline{(\nabla u)}_{Q_{1}}\cdot x\right|^{2}\leq C {\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}}\left(u_{t}^{2}+\left| D^{2}u \right|^{2}\right).
$$
Proof: We prove this inequality by contradiction. If not true, there exists $u_{k}$ such that
$$
1={\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}} \left|u_k-(\bar{u}_k)_{Q_{1}}-\overline{(\nabla u)}_{Q_{1}}\cdot x\right|^{2}\geq k\int\left((u_k)_{t}^{2}+\left| D^{2}u_k \right|^{2}\right).
$$
(Why is the left-hand side equal to $1$?)
Let $v_{k}=u_k-(\bar{u}_k)_{Q_{1}}-\overline{(\nabla u)}_{Q_{1}}\cdot x$. Then
$$
{\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}}(v_{k})_{t}^{2}+\int\left|D^{2} v_{k}\right|^{2}+\int\left|v_{k}\right|^{2}\leq C
$$
(Why does this inequality hold?)
and
$$
{\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}} v_{k}={\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}}\nabla v_{k}=0.
$$
(I calculated ${\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}}\nabla v_{k}=0$, but how to get ${\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}} v_{k}=0$?)
Let $v$ be the weak limit of $v_{k}$. Then we have, up to a subsequence,
$$
v_{k}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightarrow}v,v_{k}\stackrel{L^{2}}{\rightharpoonup}v,v_{k}{\rightharpoonup} v \;\text{in}\; W_{*}^{2,2}=\left\{v|v\in L^{2},D^{2}v\in L^{2},v_{t}\in L^{2}\right\}.
$$
(How to obtain this convergence result? As far as I can determine, it is relevant to weak compactness.)
Then it is easy to see
$$
D^{2}v=0,\,v_{t}=0,
$$
i.e.，
$$
v=Ax+B\;\text{and}\;\left|v\right|^{2}=1,
$$
$$
B={\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}} v=0,\;\text{and}\; {\int\hspace{-1.05em}-}_{Q_{1}}\nabla v=A=0.
$$
(What is the thought of the rest of proof?)
I hope someone gives me some necessary description in detail. Any help would be appreciated.

I've made some minor changes. Please look at the changes to ensure I have not changed your intended meaning. Also, I do not know what "I master how to use this method to obtain the interior estimates of solutions in elliptical case." means. Does this mean you HAVE mastered this method, or does this mean you WISH to master this method? Also, since the next sentence mentions "second part", what role does the "first part" play in that sentence? (continued)

Finally, does the paper only deal with interior estimates and you want to apply the estimates to obtain solutions, or does the paper discuss interior estimates AND then applies the estimates to obtain solutions? NOTE: I know almost nothing about this topic, so some of my questions might have answers clear to an expert, but I think a bit more clarity with what I have asked about would improve your question.
